# How does Git detect the normal repository which you pull from?

Tags: git, git-pull

In [Git-config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) you can see:

> simple - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added
>   safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different
>   from the local one.
>
> When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you
>   ***normally pull from***, work as current.

But how `Git` can detect the repository which we normally pull from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" repository for each branch is whatever is recorded under that branch's `remote` setting.

Suppose, for instance, that you are on branch `feature3`:

```
$ git config --get branch.feature3.remote
bells
```

Now you check out branch `bug7` instead; check its remote, and compare to `feature3`'s setting:

```
$ git checkout bug7
[...]
$ git config --get branch.bug7.remote
whistles
$ git config --get branch.feature3.remote
bells
```

If you are on branch `bug7` and push, git is pushing to the "normal" repository if and only if you are pushing to `whistles`.  If you are on branch `feature3` and push, git is pushing to the "normal" repository if and only if you are pushing to `bells`.